# pt space between left and right sides of frame?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, babel

[image]

I edit the footline width in beamer. but it not comes what i need solution. i need spaces between left and and right side frame some pt space.

Comment: And which theme do you use? Please start the code from `\documentclass`.

Comment: Have you tried \framewidth?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.